# Modifying currently selected document fragment with JavaScript isn't working

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to highlight the word `appl<strong>e` using the range object but I am unable to do so because the word contains a `strong` tag and the `span` tag is unable to enclose a word which contains a tag.

```
<strong>This is appl</strong>e
```

For highlighting I have used the below code after selecting the word:

```
var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
word = range.cloneContents();
range.deleteContents();
span = document.createElement('SPAN');
span.style.background = 'pink';
span.appendChild(word);
range.insertNode(span);
```

**Question**

How can I achieve highlighting of 'apple' in the above example?

Comment: Does anyone know the answer?

Comment: what is the problem? What is not working?

Comment: i want to highlight the word 'appl<strong>e' using the range object but unable to do so as span tag is unable to enclose the word which contains tags...

Comment: Can you help me regarding this?

Comment: Try to highlight with two spans, one for appl and another one for e.

Comment: That works fine for me (in Chromium 51).  "Partially selected nodes are cloned to include the parent tags necessary to make the document fragment valid" according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/cloneContents
I suggest you step through the code using the Developer Tools debugger, https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/breakpoints/step-code?hl=en

Comment: Move the clarification of the question the OP supplied in comments into the body of the question.